# Can't start the realm object server on mac os

Tags: realm, realm-object-server

I'm trying to start the realm object server on mac os.

I've download 'macOS Bundle' from here: https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/#macos

and run 'start-object-server.command' file.

But it's not working.
I get this error.

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::RealmFileException: Invalid argument
>   ./start-object-server.command: line 97:  2471 Abort trap: 6           node "$package/node_modules/.bin/realm-object-server" -c configuration.yml

I have no idea what is wrong.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the configuration file?

Comment: @Orlando I leave it defaut, I didn't change anything.

Comment: How do you start the server? I just downloaded a fresh bundle, extracted it to a directory of my choosing, and ran `$ ./start-object-server.command` in a Terminal without any issues.

Comment: @SimonAskUlsnes I did the same thing and it gave me that error message. I also did double click it, and the same result.